# Javascript object dump returns multiple objects

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I am confused with what I am seeing on a web site. From the console I type dataLayer.dump(). This outputs in the console 4 objects. Pretty sure that's weird and my research suggests a javascript method should only be able to return one object. If you need to return more than one you stick it into an array.

However, when I try dataLayer.dump()[0] I get undefined.

My question is: does anyone know if its possible to return multiple objects from one function call (not meaning an array). Or is it likely I am using the console wrong and confused myself with it? Any ideas on how to access the objects?

Comment: might be its returning an array of 4 elements all of them undefined?: [undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]

Comment: It seems likely that the purpose of a `dump()` method is to dump output to the console, so that function is probably logging things to the console itself. This is not the same as "returning" objects.

Comment: It looks like `dataLayer.dump()` returns nothing at all (which in javascript is equivalent to `undefined`. Instead it prints directly to the console and then returns nothing

Comment: No the objects it prints out in the console all are defined and have data

Comment: @Shumii: Yes. exactly. The objects *IT PRINTS OUT*

Comment: It is possible dump() just outputs to console and does not return anything. That would make sense. I may be misled, as I have been told to get data out of it

Comment: The `dataLayer` object probably has other methods that you could use to access the data. (But we don't know what they might be...)

Comment: BTW. `.dump()` is not a standard js method so it is part of whatever API dataLayer comes from

Comment: @slebetman - sorry I misunderstood your initial comment. Agree

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you type

```
dataLayer.dump
```

which will show you the code of function?

Looks like it will be something like this:

```
function dump(){
   console.log({a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:2});
}
```

Comment: I like that thinking. I will try it and see if it tells me how to get what I want.